# DropDownList selectindexchanged doesnt fire when reselecting original selected value

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

I have a form in which I have two drop downs. 
A decision in one fires the other.

The basic rule is:

Drop Down A -> select items 1,2 or 3. Drop down B loads list 1
Drop Down A -> select items 4,5 or 6. Drop down B loads list 2

This works fine on first load and save of the form. The problem is when I edit. Lets say I selected and saved item 3 in Drop Down A.

On Editing:

If I change Drop Down A, the select changed event fires every time I change it except when i reselect what was saved. 
It leaves me in a situation where I can choose 3 in Drop Down A but are left with the wrong list in Drop Down B as the event doesn't refire on that selection.

I've tried every trick I can think of but I can't seem to get around this issue.

Anyone have any suggestions?

(We've tried radiobutton lists and its the same issue. Setting the value in a variable and attempting to reset the control to clear what it thinks the original value is doesn't work either.)

Comment: That definitely is not the standard behaviour of the SelectedIndexChanged event of a DropDownList.  What other code executes in the Page_Load or SelectedIndexChanged event?  Is there code that is setting the first dropdown value even during a postback?

Comment: This is what I thought, it should not be the standard behaviour. I'm .net coding for 7 years now and never found it before. Country/State combos are for example fairly common. The control is a standard drop down. The only thing is this is a dynamic form builder i.e. I have created a system that "describes" the forms in a db and they are built on the fly based on what I call a "map set". In theory though, the front end behaviour should be the same.

Comment: I thought about was the value being set before page render on post back but that you would imagine that would prevent firing for all selections.

It just doesnt fire for the original selection. 

I've even looked at the generated html in IE developer and can't see anything being rendered into the html that would prevent it. I'm totally baffled by this. (I even had 3 other guys here at my desk all trying suggestions and none can figure it out!

Comment: Debug session is showing that the event is not raised at all when reselecting original value! I'm totally confused. (The autopostback does happen, its just the handler is never called)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that i've understood your problem completely, but consider to add an extra blank or dummy item(-- please select --) to your list and have that be the default selected item. That way as soon as a user selects a valid item it will always have changed from the original item.

Comment: That works fine on first entry as we have Please Select as the first one. Trouble is on editing. "Please Select" is no longer the original selection. Its whatever we previously selected. Switching away fires the event obviously, but switching back (such as u realise u had the correct one all along) fails to fire as .net sees no need to fire the event). I guess it wasn't designed with firing other controls in mind (properly!)